# Extract Values from incorrect Js Date Object?

Tags: javascript

I've build a function which checks if a date parts *values* are valid :

*Bad* value  example :

```
new Date(2012,3,44) = 
Mon May 14 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

[**Here**](http://jsbin.com/ihibag/3/edit) is the function ( its arguments are being sent by me `separately` !)

```
function isDate(year, month, day)
{
   ...
}

alert(isDate( 2001,2,29));
```

However , I have a problem.

If I have an invalid date object like :  `var t= new Date(2001,2,44)`  : 
And I want to send it to my function , I need to extract its values.

*How* can I extract the `44` value  + `2` value ?

```
t.getDate() //13
t.getMonth() //3   (days went from march to april)
```

any help ?

Comment: Why do you create the `new Date` before checking its values?

Comment: As @Amaan eluded to, you should call your 'isDate()' function first, then once you've established the values are valid, create a new Date() object from those values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't extract the value `44` from the `Date` object, because it's not there.

When creating a `Date` object with out of range values, the values will be adjusted so that it becomes a valid date.

The components of a `Date` object always forms a valid date. If you want to check if the values are valid, you have to do that before creating the `Date` object, or use the `Date` object to check them:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, day);
if (d.getFullYear() == year && d.getMonth() == month && d.getDate() == day) {
  // components were valid
}
```

Comment: +1, but there is no need to check all three parts, any two will do. Worth noting and checking with the OP that the month number supplied is the calendar month number less one since JS dates are zero based (January is zero).

Comment: @RobG: Yes, that's right, provided that the year is one of the parts that you check. I think that the op is aware of the month numbering, as he is calling 3 april.